# Geotagging using 'Open in Google Earth'

Tags: google-earth

I'm placing icons showing the positions of photos. But I'm baffled why I'm getting the warning message shown below. I hope that my screenshot will make the problem clearer than a wordy text description.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The obscure solution is that when the new photo has been placed, it should NOT be simply dragged to its appropriate folder (as I have instinctively been doing) but CUT and then pasted.

The warning message will not then reappear next time.

Don't understand why this works but happy to have re-discovered it!

[image: Annotated screenshot]